# trying to align items inside a container whose parent container is header

Tags: html, css, header, containers, alignment

I have a `header` container and inside it I have 3 containers for `header` components `header__left` , `header__middle` and `header__right` ,I have given  each of these components a parent container that I  want to later use to `align` child items with , I basically want to `align` items inside `header__left` container but whenever I try to add `margin-left` to make `h1` go to the right side of the `header__left` container it doesn't work

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

header{
    background-color: gray;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

#logo img{
 
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

#brand{

    width: 200px;
    
}

#brand h1{

    margin-left: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="header__left">
                <div id="brand">
                    <h1>Brand</h1>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="header__middle">

                <div id="logo">
                    <img src="phonix.png" alt="">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="header__right">

                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#">hOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">stuff</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>


        </div>
    </header>

</body>
```

Comment: text-align for ```#brand```

Answer (score 0):

as i see you are using two factors on the margin-left property.
lets take a look at this part of your code :

```
#brand h1{

margin-left: 0 auto;}
```

the margin-left property cant get two factors. its just use on of this items (number, percentage or auto)

so you can use something like `margin-left: 10px;` to move your Brand html to right.